# In an SVG element, are viewbox units the same as width etc. units?

Tags: html, svg

My html document has multiple `<svg>` elements (all produced by Mathjax).

Here is an example of the `<style>` section of one such `<svg>` element:-

```
<svg style=
"vertical-align: -1.469ex;" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
width="31.502ex" height="4.518ex" 
role="img" focusable="false" 
viewBox="0 -1347.5 13923.7 1997" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" aria-hidden="true">
```

Is it correct to assume that the units of the `viewbox` are the same as the units for `vertical-align`, `width`&  `height`, i.e. `ex`?

Comment: This link explains the relationship between viewport and viewbox quite well IMO:- [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/svg-svg-viewbox](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/svg-svg-viewbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `viewBox` sets the coordinate system that the SVG will be drawn on. It controls how the graphic will be scaled. Its unit is independent of the units of the `width` and `height` attribute.

This picture is the best visual explanation of the `viewBox` that I can find.
[image]

Back to your example, you have `viewBox=0 -1347.5 13923.7 1997". You have defined a user coordinate system with 13923.7 user units horizontally and 1997 user units vertically. The origin of the coordinate system is (0, -1347.5), which means 1347.5 units above the origin.

This coordinate system will be fit within a space 31.502ex wide and 4.518ex tall.

You are trying to display:

- 31.502ex (`width` of the element) on 13923.7 width unit -> 1 width unit = 31.5020ex / 13923.7 = 0.0023 ex
- 4.518ex (`height` of the element) on 1997 height unit -> 1 height unit = 4.518ex / 1997 = 0.0023ex

Given these values, your graphics will be likely offscreen and very small.

Comment: Thanks. This made me realize that a pictorial explanation is much clearer to me than a textual one.  I found a comprehensive descritption here:- [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/svg-svg-viewbox](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/svg-svg-viewbox).

Answer (score 2):

No. `viewBox` describes which rectangle will be rendered of
the [viewport](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#TermSVGViewport). Its user space coordinate system is unitless, but can be written also as `px`.

Comment: Also, the units of measurement inside an SVG (for paths, polygons, etc) are also unitless - despite Inkscape allowing you to choose mm,cm,pt,px,etc.